# PlayOnLinux does not show my application in the list of installed

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

I recently installed Hearthstone, and let me play with it. But when i closed battle.net client and game, the installation window was running. It was waiting for the installation's end. I close this windows... Re-open playonlinux, and there was nothing in my application list.

However there is my hearthstone device in folder PlayOnLinux's virtual drives...

How can I refresh my list?

(Sorry for my english... and thanks for help)

Answer (score 5):

Someone helped me on playonlinux forum and the solution is simple.

Response:

" You can try "fixing" this by creating shortcuts manually (Configure button > (select the virtual drive) > General tab > "Make a shortcut from this virtual drive" button) "